# Why i am getting IO::Uncompress::Unzip::unzip: input filename is undef or null string message?

Tags: linux, perl, unzip

I am having  a folder with many zip files. I need to get any of these zip file, extract it  and get a particular file from the ziped file. I am using IO::Uncompress::Unzip module for this.
I have my perl script as below:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use IO::Uncompress::Unzip qw(unzip $UnzipError);
use strict;
my $propath ="/home/test/prroot/Projects/";
my $proj = "/home/Ras/projectroot/projects.txt";
my @projlist = `cat $proj`;
foreach my $pr(@projlist){
chomp($pr);
my $projname = $pr;
my $projtemp = $pr;
$projname =~ s/ /\_/g;
my $replace1 = "%28"; #escaping special characters from project name
my $replace2 = "%29";
my $replace3 = "%26";
my $replace4 = "%2C";
$projname =~ tr/ /_/;
$projname =~ s/\(/$replace1/g;
$projname =~ s/\)/$replace2/g;
$projname =~ s/\&/$replace3/g;
$projname =~ s/\,/$replace4/g;
chomp($projname);
my $dir = $propath.$projname;
chomp($dir);
my @res = glob "$dir/*.zip";
my @res1 = split '/',$res[$#res];
my $out = chdir $dir;
my $input = "$res1[$#res1]";
my $output = "/home/Ras/projectroot/xmlres/result$projname.xml";
my $status = unzip $input => $output, Name => "data";

}
```

The file /home/Ras/projectroot/projects.txt includes more than 100 project names. For each project name there is a folder under the path /home/test/prroot/Projects/. Inside the projectname folder there are zip files. I need to read particular file named data from the zip file. I am able to read the output for 13 files as /home/Ras/projectroot/xmlres/result$projname.xml. But after that no result. Please help me on this.

Comment: You put your "%28" replacement strings between double quotes. They are therefore compouted as the hash called "28".
You should replace this by simple quotes.
using use strict;use warnings; at the beginning of your script would catch this kind of errors at compile time.
That may not be the only error but I think it is one.

Comment: I am getting output for some of the projects around 13 projects. But after that unzip not happening.

Comment: And might it be possibly because the 14th project has special characters that the 13 first don't?

Comment: I spotted another error: you put "my" just before your substitution, line 11. I don't what kind of weird behaviour it can trigger, but that's certainly not what you want to do. Seriously, you should add "use warnings;" at the beginning of your script. It really helps avoiding that kind of problem.

Comment: Yes that was an error. Removed it.

Comment: Even i tried removing the 14th project , but again i am facing the same issue. There is no special characters with this project name.

Comment: I think you should add "or die 'unzip failed: $UnzipError\n";' just after your call to unzip. Like that you know why it fails.

Comment: @DavidVerdin Double quotes don't interpolate hashes. `"%28"` is the same as `'%28'`.

Comment: Another day, another thing I learn. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unzip was giving data error. I did a modification in my script and it helped.

```
my $status = `unzip -p $input "data" > $output`
```

By adding above line replacing unzip $input => $output, Name => "data" helped in solving the issue.
Without going for extraction of zip file, it is just reading the data content and i am able to meet the requirement. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

'As I don't know how your data look like, I provide a - slightly - improved version of your script here (adding the error handling).

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use IO::Uncompress::Unzip qw(unzip $UnzipError);
use File::Find;
use strict;use warnings;
my $propath ="/home/test/prroot/Projects/";
my $proj = "/home/Ras/projectroot/projects.txt";
my $output_dir = "/home/Ras/projectroot/xmlres/";
my @projlist = `cat $proj`;
my $projname;
foreach my $pr (@projlist){
    chomp($pr);
    $projname = $pr;
    $projname =~ s/ /\_/g;
    $projname =~ tr/ /_/;
    $projname =~ s/\(/%28/g;
    $projname =~ s/\)/%29/g;
    $projname =~ s/\&/%26/g;
    $projname =~ s/\,/%2C/g;
    print "$dir\n";

    find({ wanted => \&find_zip}, $dir);
}

sub find_zip {
    my $filename = $File::Find::name;
    print "$filename\n";
    if ($filename =~ /zip$/ ) {
        unless( unzip $filename => $output_dir.'result'.$projname.'.xml', Name => "data" ) {
            warn "$filename: $UnzipError";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh. Reading your code, I realize that you expect your zip files to be below several level of recursive directories. As far as I understanf, glob will only check the first directory level. So if your zip is in dir1/dir2/file.zip and you check dir1, you won't find the zip file. In that case, using File::find would be better.

Comment: I made a new version with File::Find.

Comment: And it still has global variables, which is bad. But that's a quick fix.

Comment: I just need to check the first directory level for zip file. Zip file is directly under /home/test/prroot/Projects/projectname/ . There are many zip files under that . But i just need to get one of them and read file inside that zip file.

Comment: OK. Now is the time to admit that I don't understand. could you please produce a sample of your directory hierachy and the output of the error produced by your script? It is very difficult to help you without more informations.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is that the script is attempting to unzip all the files you expect.

Then see if unzip is complaining.

Try this

```
   print "About to unzip '$input' to '$output'\n" ;
   my $status = unzip $input => $output, Name => "data"
       or die "unzip from '$input' to '$output' failed: $UnzipError\n";
```

Comment: Unzip was giving data error. I did a modification in my script and it helped.